# Azure Function POST request shows as unauthorized when testing from Swagger

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, swagger, openapi

I have created an azure function (HTTP triggered with Open API) and deployed to azure. The endpoints working good. I am getting response when testing from Postman

Swagger UI also loading. But when trying to post from Swagger it keeps saying 401 unauthorized. But I have copied the function key from Azure portal (below screen shot) and specified that in authorize popup with in swagger.

[image]

But it still saying unauthorized.

When I copy the URL from portal for the http endpoint, it looks like this

https://myurls-asev3.appserviceenvironment.net/api/ObjectRead?code=mycode

Here mycode is exactly the same one I copied from function keys. But the only difference is, the code is attached as a query string in url when I copied the URL from portal
[image]

But in swagger it sends as header.

But in function configuration I designed it to accept as header.

```
[FunctionName("ObjectRead")]
[OpenApiOperation(operationId: "Run", tags: new[] { "name" })]
[OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Header)]
[OpenApiRequestBody("application/json", typeof(FileDetails))]
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "The OK response")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"ObjectRead function triggered at {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("O")}.");

    var requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileDetails>(requestBody);
    var responseMessage = await _objectReadService.ReadAsync(data.FileName, data.FilePath).ConfigureAwait(false);

    _logger.LogInformation($"ObjectRead function completed at {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("O")}.");
    return responseMessage.Length != 0 ? new FileStreamResult(responseMessage, "application/octet-stream") { FileDownloadName = data.FileName} : new NotFoundObjectResult("Unable to retrieve the file or File not found.");
}
```

Above code snippet 3rd line I have mentioned the key as header

Even why its not working in swagger and in url why the code still shows as query string

Comment: the name of the header should be `x-functions-key`.

Comment: did that work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#api-key-authorization):

> ```http
> https://<APP_NAME>.azurewebsites.net/api/<FUNCTION_NAME>?code=<API_KEY>
> ```
>
> The key can be included in a query string variable named `code`, as above. It can also be included in an `x-functions-key` HTTP header. The value of the key can be any function key defined for the function, or any host key.

so your attirbute should looks like that:

```cs
[OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "x-functions-key", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Header)]
```